# Load custom CSS in a facebook app

Tags: php, facebook

I've written an app in PHP and want to use it in a Canvas page on facebook. I need to detect that the app has been loaded by facebook and load a specific CSS file so that it displays correctly.  (I have a number of CSS files, for e.g. mobile.css for mobile devices)

I've written the CSS file for when the app is loaded via Facebook but I'm having problems detecting when the app is displayed through facebook.

I included the facebook PHP API library and thought using the getUser() function would be enough. i.e. if getUser() == 0, it's not loaded via Facebook but this doesn't work in all cases.

Is there a fool proof way of detecting if an app is loaded though facebook?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "loaded through facebook"? Do you mean a canvas app?  Mobile Facebook app?  Website with Facebook login?

Comment: Apologies, this is a canvas app. I'm fairly new to this and have been following [this fb tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/)

Comment: Please edit your question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a Facebook canvas app, you can check for a valid signed_request parameter as part of the REQUEST variables. If you are using the Facebook PHP SDK, it has a getSignedRequest function already which will return null if there is no signed request.  Otherwise, follow the [signed_request documentation from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/).

Comment: I'm missing something about using the signed_request param. I've tried using getSignedRequest() but it returns an empty string. Also tried `
  $signed_request = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
` This also returns an empty string

Comment: The user has to authorize the app first before you'll get a signed_request parameter.